# Linux xsetwacom setting equivalent to Windows wacom driver mapping

Tags: linux, drivers, bamboo

In the Windows drivers for Wacom tablets, you have the option of mapping (a) the hole monitor to a specific area of the tablet, something like this:

[image]

I can't find an option in the `xsetwacom` command to emulate this behavior. Is this posible?

Answer (score 1):

For using *xsetwacom* to do it, look here:
http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Dual_and_Multi-Monitor_Set_Up#Coordinate_Transformation_Matrix

You basically have to do it by hand, calculating the proportions of your monitor and translating them to tablet size. The instruction in the link explain how to map the whole tablet to the screen, with distortion. It should be easy (if you get the math behind it) to adapt it to not distort.

**BUT** there are GUI apps too:
http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/External_applications#Utilities

If you're on KDE you maybe want to take a look at the "Wacom tablet" settings module. It's not yet where the windows driver is, but it lets you do what you want, set different profiles and more. I must say that it's not working well for me on Debian Jessy, but the version on the repos is an pretty old. (You don't say what distro are you using, usually relevant in a linux question)

There's also a GNOME applet, never tried it, but seems good (even better?).